# Get Html generate from inside the Usercontrol?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, lifecycle

I develop a custom usercontrol. For a specific need, I have to get the html generate from usercontrol inside it and display only it in the page's body.

I think it's possible overloading RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) but I don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can render the control in memory, have it on a string, and then print this string somewhere on your page as you say. Here is the code that loads the control and renders it on  memory, then have the results on a string.

```
    // load the control
    var oTesto = Page.LoadControl("Testo.ascx");

    // here you need to run some initialization of your control
    //  because the page_load is not loading now.

    // a string writer to write on it
    using(TextWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
      // a html writer
      using(HtmlTextWriter GrapseMesaMou = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
      {
        // now render the control inside the htm writer
        oTesto.RenderControl(GrapseMesaMou);

        // here is your control rendered output.
        strBuild = stringWriter.ToString();
      }
    }
```

To capture the rendering of your control you can use the [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338806(VS.71).aspx) as:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

    // now the control is inside the htmlWriter as final rendered text
    base.Render(htmlWriter);

    // here is how to make the control render itself
    // base.Render(writer);
}
```

You place the render inside your control class.

Comment: Thanks to you but i want to do this inside the usercontrol. I can't do in the web page. So i think I have to do it during the usercontrol lifecycle

Comment: thanks ! It's what's I'm looking for. But i have a problem. In this control I insert another usercontrol programmatycally but it'isn't add to the TextWriter. Any solutions ?

Comment: Wow, exactly what I need to load parts of my page using ajax and a little .net ashx handler!  loadtemplate.ashx?tpl=edituser&lang=pt-BR.

Comment: @FredericMalenfant Yes this little code have a lot of power, if you find how to use it...